# Highlight found key word VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual studio 2010, and when I want to find a keyword (Ctrl+F). It seem that the found keyword is not highlight at all, I am very difficult to recogniza it. How can I customize this to get a more highlight effect

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) from Microsoft; they introduce a Quick Find feature that highlights matches throughout the file.

As an alternative (if you wanted highlighting just so you could see at a glance what/how many matches you have in your file), you can try `Find in Files (Ctrl+Shift+F)`, choose `Current document` as the scope, and a list of all matching lines will become available in the current `Find Results` window.  This may or may not work for you.

Comment: I don't want to install more plugin. I just want to customize it in Tool/Option... Is it posible?

Comment: Nope.  You have to install the plugin.  I believe VS2012 has Quick Find as a built-in.